# unit testing ef datamodel

Tags: c#, testing, tdd, nunit

I'm working on a personal c# project in my spare time. Before this projected I haven't really done any unit testing, but I that it was time to learn so I read a couple of tutorials/blogs and installed NUnit and Testdriven.Net in VS2010 and I think I got the basics covered now.

My project uses a data model, which I created using EF4. I've also created a repository to retrieve the data and now I want to test that repository. How should I test it? Can I somehow avoid making calls to the database everytime I want to test a method in the Repository?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use mocking frameworks to create "fake" versions of your repositories.  [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) is one I use very often.  Essentially, you write code to fake return values of your repositories based on configuration...

```
var mock = new Mock<YourObject>();
mock.Setup(m => m.DoSomething().Returns(true));
var result = mock.Object.DoSomething();
Assert.IsTrue(result);
```

Here's a good tutorial on getting [started with Moq](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/12/tdd-introduction-to-moq.aspx) by Stephen Walther.

Comment: If I decide to go with Moq while I then have to define an interface for every entity in the model?

Comment: I found this tutorial http://andrewblogs.com/blog/moq-testing-tutorial/ but I cant add moq.contrib to the namespace. Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

define an IRepository interface.  have a real implementation of it that uses the database.  have a fake implementation of it that returns dummy objects for the purpose of unit testing